# Why there are routing packages when we have navigator in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have been working on flutter for a long but I didn't get that when we have Navigator for routing in our app then why there are so many routing packages out there on pub.dev like sailor, fluro beamer and list goes on.
Are there packages better than navigator or is there something else?

Answer (score 1):

Packages like [routemaster](https://pub.dev/packages/routemaster), [beamer](https://pub.dev/packages/beamer) simplify using the new Navigator 2.0, the implementation of which can be a bit tedious. You can keep using the imperative Navigator, if you need simple tasks like `pop()` and `push()` but if you need features like [deep-linking](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking) and changing stack dynamically, then you would have to use Navigator 2.0 and packages like these simplify their implementation.

[Navigator 2.0](https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade)